# c and assembly makefile

Tags: c, assembly, makefile

We have an assignment from university including coding in c and assembly together.
we were provided with a makefile that should be good to go for running one task code.
but for some reason I got an error.
this is the makefile we got (which should be complete for task1 as they say)

```
CC      :=  gcc -m32
CC_FLAGS    :=  -Wall -g
ASM     :=  nasm
ASM_FLAGS   :=  -f elf -g
LINK        :=  ld

SRC_DIR     :=  src
OBJ_DIR     :=  obj
LIST_DIR    :=  list
BIN_DIR     :=  bin

all: task1 # task2

task1:  $(OBJ_DIR)/main1.o $(OBJ_DIR)/task1.o
    $(CC) -o $(BIN_DIR)/task1.bin $(OBJ_DIR)/main1.o $(OBJ_DIR)/task1.o

# task2:
# add your makefile code here...
# uncomment task2 in section 'all'

# .c/.s compile rules
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.s
    $(ASM) $(ASM_FLAGS) $< -o $@ -l $(subst .o,.lst,$(subst $(OBJ_DIR),$(LIST_DIR),$@))

clean:
    rm $(BIN_DIR)/*.bin $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(LIST_DIR)/*.lst
```

the error I get is:

```
make: * No rule to make target 'obj/main1.o', needed by 'task1'.  Stop.
```

any idea what is wrong? been trying for couple of hours already. Thank you!

Comment: Well, does `src/main1.s` or `src/main1.c` exist? Make sure case matches.

Comment: I can't believe that was the problem the whole time. they gave us different names for the c/s files .. Thank you, solved the problem!